# Calculating GUI position from game space position

Tags: javascript, math, vector, game-engine

I am creating my own game engine in Java Script. I have many things working great but one problem I am haveing is converting `game space` coordinates into `screen space` coordinates.

In my camera class I calulate the screen position of any given entity like so

```js
draw(Engine, Entity, FollowEntity){
    var x = Entity.render_position.x - (FollowEntity.render_position.x - Engine.rendersize.x / 2) - (Entity._get_render_size().x / 2);
    var y = Entity.render_position.y - (FollowEntity.render_position.y - Engine.rendersize.y / 2) - (Entity._get_render_size().y / 2);
    var _x = Entity.render_position.x - (FollowEntity.render_position.x - Engine.rendersize.x / 2);
    var _y = Entity.render_position.y - (FollowEntity.render_position.y - Engine.rendersize.y / 2);

    Engine.ctx.save();  
    Engine.ctx.translate(_x, _y);
    Engine.ctx.rotate(Entity.rotation * Math.PI / 180);
    Engine.ctx.translate(-_x, -_y);
    Engine.ctx.drawImage(Engine.rasterizer.get_cached_img(Entity), x, y); /**/
    Engine.ctx.restore();       
}
```

I have tried extensively to aid myself in solving this with ChatGPT to no avail.

here is my current attempt

```js
// Calculate the position of the entity in the game world
var gameX = this.ContextEntity.position.x;
var gameY = this.ContextEntity.position.y;

// Calculate the position of the camera in the game world
var cameraX = this.Engine.follow_entity.position.x;
var cameraY = this.Engine.follow_entity.position.y;

// Calculate the position of the entity on the screen, taking into account the difference in pixel size between the game entities and the GUI elements
var screenX = (gameX - cameraX) * this.GUI.rasterizer.pixel_size / this.Engine.rasterizer.pixel_size;
var screenY = (gameY - cameraY) * this.GUI.rasterizer.pixel_size / this.Engine.rasterizer.pixel_size;

// Adjust the position of the entity on the screen to take into account the size of the entity
screenX -= this.ContextEntity._get_render_size().x / 2;
screenY -= this.ContextEntity._get_render_size().y / 2;
```

```js
gameToScreen(game) {
    var game1 = (typeof game.x !== 'undefined') ? game.x : game[0];
    var game2 = (typeof game.y !== 'undefined') ? game.y : game[1];
    var x = game1 - (this.control_entity._get_render_midpoint().x - (this.rendersize.x / 2)) / this.rasterizer.pixel_size;
    var y = game2 - (this.control_entity._get_render_midpoint().y - (this.rendersize.y / 2)) / this.rasterizer.pixel_size;
    return new Vec2(Math.floor(x), Math.floor(y));
}
```

and here is another previous attempt which only seems to work when my pixel multipliers for the Engine entities are 0

the engine is running at https://soft-crab-57.telebit.io

Any help would be greatly appriciated.